# Rasperry Pi 0W keeps crashing with segmentation fault

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm running a Rasperry Pi 0W with a usb camera to take photos and send to my own server with a Python script. It takes photos during the day and restarts with a cronjob every morning at 4am. It does a good job for about a week and then crashes hard. It gives a segmentation fault when I try to restart the python script. The only thing that works after that is completely wiping the memory and reinstalling Raspberry Pi OS Lite (headless).

The server receiving the photos runs on nodejs with express. That doesn't seem to cause any problems.

What could cause the crash?

```
from os import system
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import subprocess

system('rm /home/esjee/photo-monster/photos/*.jpg')

def capture_image(file_path):
    subprocess.call(["fswebcam", "-r", "1280x720", "-S 15", "--no-banner", file_path])

def take_photo():
    name = datetime.timestamp(date)
    filePath = '/home/esjee/photo-monster/photos/{}.jpg'.format(name)
    
    try:
        capture_image(filePath)
    except:
        pass

    headers = {'Origin': 'some origin'}
    photo = {'photo': open(r'/home/esjee/photo-monster/photos/{}.jpg'.format(name), 'rb')}
    payload = { 'foo':'bar'}
    url='https://somewebsite.com/photo-monster'
    
    try:
        r = requests.post(url=url, data=payload, headers=headers, files=photo)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)
        pass
    
    try:
        r.connection.close()
    except:
        pass
    
    try:
        system('rm /home/esjee/photo-monster/photos/{}.jpg'.format(name))
    except:
        pass


x=1
while x > 0:
    take_photo()
    date = datetime.today()
    if (date.hour > 22 and date.minute > 45):
        break
```

Comment: My bet would be on SD card getting corrupted. You can try running https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/sd-card-speed-test/ You can install it through "apt-get install agnostics"

Comment: Also try asking on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I do have the right SD card, but the way I set up the infinite loop might be causing the issue. I'll try a callback function instead. Hopefully that works :)